# Appcelerator Titanium with php

Tags: php, ide, appcelerator

I just know about appcelerator with php. Using web technologies, Can we develop Desktop application that can run on all OS ?

Thanks,
Dinesh Kumar Manoharan

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the exact examples you are looking for [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/php).

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Desktop works for Linux, OSX, and Windows. Most likely just modern versions - I wouldn't count on it working in OSX 10.0, Windows 95, etc.

Comment: Thanks,Kindly suggest some URL for appcelerator with php examples

Comment: Have you tried the Appcelerator website? Plenty of examples for you there, as well as the answer to your original question re: OS.

Comment: I will look on the site now. Thanks